# Creating custom permissions for 365 management api

Tags: azure, api, permissions, office365, office365api

I am curious if there is a way to create custom permissions for the 365 management api to be used for an app registration.

I would like to collect activity data of a select group of users instead of using the out of the box permission ActivityFeed.Read which seems to grant read permission to the entire organisation.

[365 Management API - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7xuz.png)

Answer (score 0):

***Yes, you can create custom API permissions for the App registration.***

Go to [**Azure Ad Admin Center**](https://aad.portal.azure.com/?bundlingKind=DefaultPartitioner&configHash=LQ4BTTisPkqQ&env=aad&l=en.en-us&pageVersion=10.83.0.1117060.220720-1800), select Azure Active Directory and select your application:

[image]

In the manifest, check for the **`oauth2Permissions`** section and add the custom permissions in the above section:

[image]

To know how to do it in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Custom Permissions in Azure AD Applications by Andrew Connell](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/leverage-custom-permissions-in-azure-ad-applications/)